Why the structure pointer "p" in the following code is not updating with the "temp" value assigned to it?
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    int data;       
    struct node *link;  
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    struct node *p;
    p = NULL;
 
    Append(&p , 1); // Append adds a node to the end of linked list
    Append(&p , 2);
    Append(&p , 3);
    AddatBeginning (p, 100);
    Display(p);    // Displays Elements of Linked List
    return 0;
}

// The function AddatBeginning adds a node at the beginning of linked list 'p'
void AddatBeginning (struct node *p, int num)
{
    struct node *f, *temp = NULL;
    f = p;
    temp = (struct node *)malloc (sizeof(struct node));
    temp->data = num;
    temp->link = f;
    p=temp;
}

I ran the code in DevC++ but not getting the expected output - 100, 1, 2, 3.
The output I got is 1,2,3.
On debugging the code, I found that the expression "p=temp;" in function "AddatBeginning" is not working. P is not pointing where temp is pointing after the execution of statement. Why is it so?

How do you know how to pass p to Append function, but not how to do the same Thing with another function?

You are coding to the original, archaic C90 standard — C23 was released in October 2024.  You should have declared AddatBeginning() before calling it, which would have pointed out that you're passing a struct node ** where a struct node * is expected.  Also, you use neither argc nor argv, so you would be well advised to define int main(void) { … } instead of int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { … }.

Sidenote: int main(int argc, char *argv[]) when you don't use the arguments might as well be: int main(void)

@JonathanLeffler the OP does not pass a struct node ** to AddatBeginning() but a struct node * as expected by the function.

@Gerhardh — oh, yes — my bad.  I was looking at the Append() lines which have &p (a struct node **).  The functions should all have been declared before they were used — not doing so is a quarter-century out of date!

You are passing the pointer p  by value
AddatBeginning (p, 100);

It means that the function deals with a copy of the original passed pointer. Any changes of the copy like that
 p=temp;

leave the original pointer unchanged.
That is a function parameter that is a local variable of the function is initialized by the value of the passed argument and within the function you deal with this separate local variable.
You need to pass the pointer p by reference. In C passing by reference means passing an object indirectly through a pointer to it. Thus dereferencing the passed pointer you have a direct access to the original object that in turn can be a pointer.
So the function will look the following way
int AddatBeginning (struct node **p, int num)
{
    struct *temp = malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );
    int success = temp != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        temp->data = num;
        temp->link = *p;
        *p = temp;
    }

    return success;
}

and can be called like
AddatBeginning( &p, 100 );

or
if ( !AddatBeginning( &p, 100 ) )
{
    // error message
}

By the way the function Append
Append(&p , 1);
       ^^

accepts the original pointer by reference.:)
Pay attention to that the called functions shall be declared in the program before their usage.
